# c# Datagridview row color listview items

Tags: c#, listview, datagridview

I have 1 DataGridView and 1 ListView I can Transfer of rows between a Datagridview to a Listview. I added one more foreach into my code.

I would like to compare the datagridview items with the listview items. I want to change the color of the row in datagridview if it is the same in the listview. but the code is not working.

Is there another alternative?

```
 ListViewItem item;
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV_LISTE.SelectedRows)
 {
   item = new ListViewItem(row.Cells["Personel_ID"].Value.ToString());

   item.SubItems.Add(row.Cells["PersonelADSOYAD"].Value.ToString());
   item.SubItems.Add(row.Cells["Gorev"].Value.ToString());
   LV_Secilenler.Items.Add(item);

   foreach (ListViewItem items in LV_Secilenler.Items)
   {
     if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Personel_ID"].Value) == Convert.ToInt32(items.SubItems["Personel_ID"].Text))
     {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
     }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point at the if condition and check what values are seen for both the row.Cells["Personel_ID"].Value and items.SubItems["Personel_ID"].Text

Change Backcolor to SelectionBackColor
row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.selectionbackcolor?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: If (LV_Secilenler.Items.FindByValue(row.Cells["Personel_ID"].Value.ToString())){  row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;} try to Find the Row Cell value in ListItems if found change color else not